# How to host a bot server on a hosting service?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made a simple bot application with C# console application which interacts with users via http requests. Now I want to publish it on a Host service so that it will be always online. 
 The steps I wanted to take is to export all of the bot server's class into a class library and make a Asp.net application and upload it to a host service (maybe with a Plesk panel) and let the asp.net make instance of server class and start it. 
 
But the problem is, every time I open a browser and make request to the asp.net application it would dispatch a new thread for me from thread pool so everytime it would make a new instance of the server class and start it. So how can I access to same server class?

Is it even possible?

I know that I can buy vps and run my console application there but isn't it wasting resources for a simple bot server application?
sorry if my question is not so clear.

Comment: ASP.NET really isn't designed for running a service - it's for handling requests and their responses. You can get around some of those issues with a bit of work (e.g. having a static instance of the "bot"), but the effort is ultimately futile - whenever the application or the pool is recycled, your "service" will die, and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: You need to persist data between requests. In an HTTP context, usually a "session" is used for this. If you want the persisted data to be the same for all clients (not just all requests from one client), you have a bigger problem.

Comment: So there is no good way to run such a service on a Hosting service, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it but it's not the recommended way to do it.

Create a class that has getObj() that returns the only running object, if there is no object it creates one and returns it.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Have the object make a thread that runs in the background. 
Have the thread save it's variables to a sql server for redundancy.

When you create the object the first time. Read the variables from the sql server to recreate the state the thread was before it was killed.

In your global.asax you can initiate the thread when the application is restarted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. so its not a good idea to run a service on a Hosting service. what do you recommend? should I run it on a VPS/VDS?

Comment: That would be better, but it you have more time than money you could always try doing it the other way.

You could run it on a raspberry pi via mono aswell. Should be pretty cheap.